# Getting master Branch when using git pull with auth

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a problem with Git. I have a Project and 4 Branches V1.0, V1.1, V1.2 and master.

Now I clone V1.2 with this command:

```
git clone -b V1.2 --single-branch http://domain/user/project.git .
```

I get the right Version. The following commands

```
git pull
```

and

```
git pull http://user:passwd@domain/user/project.git
```

says on both commands `Already up-to-date`

But when I do the same with a lower Version 1.1, I get on the first Command a `Already up-to-date`. On the second command: git update my files to master. Why? What do I wrong?

```
git status

Auf Branch V1.1
Ihr Branch ist vor 'origin/V1.1' um 45 Commits.
```

and a

```
git branch

* V1.1
```

But the Files are from master.